# Hibernate - fetch by bean

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans

Is this theoretical query possible in hibernate?

```
Person personQuery = new Person();//(@Entity)
personQuery.setId(5);
List<Person> persons = personQuery.get("=").fetch();
```

meaning

```
SELECT * from person WHERE id=5
```

When things are simple I want to work with beans(Entities) and not HQL.
Is there an API that supports that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only by id, then you can use:

```
Person person = session.get(Person.class, 5);
```

Spring's `HibernateTempalte` has the [`findByExample`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#findByExample%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which seems like what you need.

It actually uses the hibernate criteria API:

```
Criteria executableCriteria = session.createCriteria(exampleEntity.getClass());
executableCriteria.add(Example.create(exampleEntity));
return executableCriteria.list();
```

Comment: "If it is only by id", you mean PK?

Comment: yes. I've never had a case when a field "id" did not denote a PK :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal is to not need the `session` object to do finds, updates, etc.  In Java, I haven't seen anything like that.  It has been implemented in Grails as GORM using Hibernate, and works by dynamically adding methods at runtime.

For example, you can do a straight lookup by id:

```
def item = Item.get(itemId) // finds an item with a given id
```

Or easily do a HQL query:

```
def items = Item.findAll("from Item as item where item.price < 50") // find all items where price < 50
```